# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'excluirTask')

Tags: javascript, react

Estou querendo implementar a funcionalidade de excluir individualmente o itens de uma lista, mas quando chamo a função excluirTask (ainda não implementada) ocorre o erro Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'excluirTask').

App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import uniqid from "uniqid";
import Overview from './components/overview'; 

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      task: { 
        text: '',
        id: uniqid(),
        num: 1
      },
      tasks: []
    };
    this.excluirTask = this.excluirTask.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.onSubmitTask = this.onSubmitTask.bind(this);
  }
  handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      task : {
        text: e.target.value,
        id: this.state.task.id,
        num: this.state.task.num,
      }
    });
  }; 
  onSubmitTask = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      task: { 
        text: '',
        id: uniqid(),
        num: this.state.task.num+1,
      },
      tasks: this.state.tasks.concat(this.state.task),
    });
    console.log(this.state.tasks);
  }; 
  excluirTask = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("Excluir a tarefa: " + this.task.id);
  };
  render() {
    const { task, tasks } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.onSubmitTask}>
          <label htmlFor="taskInput">Enter task</label>
          <input 
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            value={task.text} 
            type="text" 
            id="taskInput"/>
          <button type="submit">
            Add Task
          </button> 
        </form>
        <Overview tasks={tasks} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

overview.js:

```
import React from "react";

const Overview = (props) => {
  const { tasks } = props;

  return (
    <ul>
      {tasks.map((task) => {
        return (
                <div>
                    <li key={task.id}>{task.num} - {task.text}</li>
                    <button key={task.id} onclick={this.excluirTask}>Excluir</button>
                </div>
            );
      })}
    </ul>
  );
};

export default Overview;
```

index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Comment: já tentou passar o evento no click? assim por exemplo: `onClick={ e => this.excluirTask(e)`

Comment: Retorna o erro: this.excluirTask is not a function

Comment: Eu editei o arquivo overview.js, transformando a função Overview numa classe e adicionando dentro dela a função excluirTask. Isso resolveu o erro, aparentemente não da pra chamar a função excluirTask dentro de overview.js se ela estiver declarada em App.js. Mas ocorre outro erro, ela é executada automaticamente todas as vezes que é digitado conteúdo dentro do input.

Comment: Usando a notação de seta () => this.excluirTask(task.id) e a função declarada dentro de Overview da tudo certo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi o problema, o método excluir teve que ser declarado dentro da classe Overview e ele foi chamado usando declaração por chaves, pois continha um argumento:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Overview extends Component{
    excluirTask = (id) => {
        console.log("Excluir a tarefa: " );
        console.log(id);
      };
    render(){
        return (
            <ul>
            {this.props.tasks.map( (task) => {
                return (
                        <li key={task.id}>{task.num} - {task.text} <button onClick={() => this.excluirTask(task.id)}>Excluir</button></li>
                    );
            })}
            </ul>
        );
    }  
}

export default Overview;
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).